# unable to understand the plumbing in Rxjs

Tags: rxjs

What I have understood so far about `Rxjs` is that an `Observable` is a stream and we can "push" new values in the stream using an `Observer`'s `next` method. Then I subscribe to the stream to receive the values. But I am unable to understand how the plumbing works. For eg.

I can create an `Observable` as

```
var observable = Rx.Observable.of('foo', 'bar');
```

Then I can do

```
var subscription =  observable.subscribe(x=>console.log(x))
```

1. Where and how an observer is created above?
2. Who is calling `next` to push value in the stream?
3. I thought that `x=>console.log(x)` is an Observer but it hasn't got a `next`
   method. How does the above code then work?

Here is another example. Below, I pass an `observer` and use its `next` method to push values but I never created an `observer` (an object which has next method).

```
var myObservable = Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
  observer.next('foo');
  setTimeout(() => observer.next('bar'), 1000);
});
myObservable.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

Comment: I think you might be looking for something like this: https://medium.com/@benlesh/learning-observable-by-building-observable-d5da57405d87

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1) Where and how an observer is created above?**

You create the Observer when you subscribe. You provide the Observer as the argument for the subscribe method. For example something like the following:

```
var subscription =  observable.subscribe(
{
next: x=>console.log(x),
error: e=>console.log(e),
complete: ()=>console.log('completed')
}
)
```

The subscribe method also accepts one or all of the methods of the Observer directly. For example something like following:

```
var subscription =  observable.subscribe(x=>console.log(x))
```

The above is the syntactic sugar for the following:

```
var subscription =  observable.subscribe(
    {
    next:x=>console.log(x)
    }
    )
```

**(2) Who is calling next to push value in the stream?**

The `next` method call is there in the codes for creating Observable (see bellow). After you subscribed (that means you have provided the Observer as the argument to the subscribe method), the following code will be executed. Carefully note that the Observer used in the following codes is the one that you provided when you subscribed. The `next` method is called here, which you defined in your Observer.

```
var myObservable = Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
  observer.next('foo');
  setTimeout(() => observer.next('bar'), 1000);
});
myObservable.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

**(3) I thought that x=>console.log(x) is an Observer but it hasn't got a next method. How does the above code then work?**

As I explained earlier, what you provided here is the `next` method of the Observer.

Comment: Thanks. Who calls ‘next’ in ‘of’? I understand now that in ‘create’ I define the values of a stream and also call ‘next’ explicitly to push the values. But in ‘of’, I only specify the values but don’t call ‘next’.  Does ‘of’ calls ‘next’? I suppose in both cases, the logic for how to handle the values is in logic of function passed in ‘subscribe’.

Comment: Yes, 'of' calls 'next' for each elements. If you see the source of 'of', you can see codes like subscriber.next(array[i]); Link to the source: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/file/es6/observable/ArrayObservable.js.html#lineNumber59